# Rewrite React conditional rendering with if in Ramda or with a monad

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, conditional-rendering

I am ramdafying a section in the this application:
https://github.com/muratkeremozcan/tour-of-heroes-react-cypress-ts/pull/110/files

90% there, one simple thing gets me.
I can rewrite a simple if  with ramda or monads in multiple ways, during prototyping:
https://github.com/muratkeremozcan/books/blob/master/Kyle-Simpson_Luis-Antecio/You-Dont-Know-JS/99_MuratsNinjaExercises/replace-if.ts

All I have left is to convert the simple conditional rendering to ramda or monad. Fn components are built to be able to return multiple renders, and the pureness of FP isn’t working out there.

Example: https://github.com/muratkeremozcan/tour-of-heroes-react-cypress-ts/blob/main/src/boys/BoyDetail.tsx#L35

```
  // rewrite in Ramda

  if (status === 'loading' || isUpdating) {
    return <PageSpinner />
  }

  if (postError || isUpdateError) {
    return <ErrorComp />
  }
```

How do we make that conditional render with if into Ramda , or a Monad?

To test:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/muratkeremozcan/tour-of-heroes-react-cypress-ts.git
cd tour-of-heroes-react-cypress-ts
yarn cy:open-ct

# run the test BoysList
```

Comment: 1. You don't have monads, the type system isn't powerful enough (you'd need HKTs and while you can get them somewhat in TS by abusing interface extension, well, see the rest of this comment). 2. Look, I love ramda as much as the next person and there are really times where it makes code clearer or easier to express. This almost certainly isn't one of them. Consider carefully how much value you're adding by obfuscating clear simple code. There's no mutation going on here, no side effects, just procedural boolean logic. Let it be.

Comment: I had to let it be :D 
What are your thoughts on swan-io/boxed? https://swan-io.github.io/boxed/
I would love your blog examples re-interpeted in swan-io.

Comment: Looks interesting, although I'm always leery of things that try to import the semantics from other languages (e.g. tagged unions, pattern matching) into JS/TS.